# Do edits to on hold questions by other users (not the OP) place the question in the reopen review queue?

Tags: support, edits, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

The [help centre about closed questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) says:

> If a question is edited by the original poster when it is marked [on hold], it will automatically be placed in a review queue to be considered for reopening.

However, the [help centre about reopening questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions) says:

> If you see a question and you disagree with the stated reason of its
>   closure, you should first try to edit the question to improve it as
>   much as possible... Closed questions that receive edits within the
>   first 5 days of closure are automatically put into a review queue to
>   be considered for reopening.

These appear to contradict each other. Does the editor need to be the OP to place the question into the reopen review queue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If any edits are made to a closed question by anyone, it will be placed in the reopen queue. The editor need not be OP to put it in the reopen queue.

If an editor is planning on improving a question which is on hold, they should be making changes *only if the changes warrant reopening the question*. This rarely occurs since most of the time the missing information or edits can only come from OP. As an editor, you should avoid making improvement edits on the question if it does nothing about the closure reason (eg: the question itself is too broad or off topic).

Comment: Thanks, is it possible then for the help centre wording to be amended?